# Columns misaligned when exporting SQL Studio query to .CSV

Tags: sql, csv, ssms, export-to-csv

I am trying to export results of query in SSMS to CSV file. I have a number of different tables, and the Export Wizard has thrown a bunch of mapping errors which I can't figure out, so I am trying to use Save As method by right-clicking the query result window. When I open up the CSV file, a number of rows are incomplete, while others are misaligned, and seemed to have shifted one column.  All column headers exported correctly. I cannot figure out how to export the results correctly.

Query is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    contract.Description,
    contract_type.type,
    Destination_City.Name_,
    contract.Tour_Summary,
    employee.First_Name,
    employee.Last_name,
    Currency_.Currency_Name,
    contract_Items.twin,
    contract.Upfront_Room_Comp,
    contract.Room_Comp_Number,
    contract.Room_Comp, 
    contract.Start_Date, 
    contract.End_Date, 
    contract.Payment_Terms

FROM 
    Contract,
    Contract_items,
    Contract_type,
    Employee,
    Currency_,
    Destination_City

WHERE
    Contract.Contract_ID=Contract_Items.Contract_ID
    and contract_items.Contract_Type_Id=contract_type.Contract_Type_Id 
    and employee.Employee_Id=Contract.Contracted_By_Employee_Id
    and Currency_.Currency_Id=contract.currency_id
    and Destination_City.Destination_City_Id=Contract_Items.Destination_City_Id
    and contract.Contracted_Date > '01/01/2014'
    and Contract_type.type = 'Hotel'
    and contract.signed = 1

ORDER BY
    employee.First_Name
```

Comment: Define misaligned columns? There is no formatting when exporting to .CVS, should be just text with commas(or another defined column separator) for separating columns,

Comment: For example when I open the CSV file, some of the First_Name results are aligned under the Tour_Summary column, Name_ results are aligned under the type column, etc.

Comment: if there no value for any given column than that whole row will be shifted over but if you import it into Excel it will still correctly go to specified column

Answer (score 0):

Try to get result in grid (default action), select whole table and copy to clipboard.

Open new Excel sheet and paste result. If you have a problem with alignment, format all columns as text and then paste.